# saving uploaded file in project directory using multer

Tags: node.js, multer

i am able to upload files in node.js using middleware called multer.but when i give destination path : '/uploads/'. files are saved in c: drive

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
   cb(null, '/uploads/')
   },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, file.originalname)
   }
 })

  var upload = multer({storage: storage});

   var emp = require('../models/employees.js');

  router.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req,res,next){
    console.log("Server: got file ");
    console.log(req.file);
    var upl = new emp({picture: req.file.originalname});
         upl.save(function(err,docs) {
           if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            }
              res.json(docs);
         });
  });
  module.exports = router;
```

i tried to give a long string path too like

```
'/users/user/webstormprojects/template/public/uploads/image/'
```

but it ends with internal server error
someone please help me so that i can be able to save my uploaded files into my project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Path Module.And then use _dirname. See the code below

```
var path = require('path')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
   cb(null, path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/'))
   },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, file.originalname)
   }
})
```

This should solve your problem. _dirname will give you the access of the directory you are working in.

Comment: with this code my program  ends with internal server error, any other idea @Aditya kumar

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your app.js or index.js file

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: week }));
```

then upload your files inside **/uploads** like this

```
destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './public/uploads');
},
```

**NB: make sure that there is uploads folder inside public folder**